# Criar select box com dados dinamicos

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, laravel

Bom dia,

queria implementar no meu projeto um select box mas em que as opções são a coluna "name" de outra tabela de base de dados, isto é, estou a criar um objeto e é possivel associar um porduto criado anteriormente através da select box que terá sempre o name dos produtos registados na base de dados. Depois de selecionar a opção pretendida a aplicação vai guardar o id do produto.

Será que alguem me consegue ajudar?

Comment: Se tiver poucos produtos use um "for" com a lista de produtos se estiver usando blade do laravel use o "foreach" para criar o html com os parâmetros desejados, se tiver muitos produtos, aconselho fazer um esquema de server-side, não tem muito segredo, use lanço de repetição, tanto no PHP Back-end ou no Javascript Front-end a depender de como estiver sua codificação.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples seria:

```html
<select id='TAG_OPTION' class='form-control'>
     @foreach ($tags as $tag)
           <option value="{{ $tag->ID_TAG }}">{{ $tag->NOME_TAG }}</option>
      @endforeach           
</select>
```